# Rotation works in iOS6 but not in iOS5

Tags: iphone, ios, orientation

I am developing an app that supports iOS 5 & 6 and it is set up to run in Landscape Mode Right only, this is working pretty well under iOS 6 - but as soon as I run it in the iOS 5 Simulator the complete View is some kind of stretched in Portrait Mode, even if the Simulator is turned into Landscape Orientation - it's just the View...

Comment: Are you using [orientation rotation methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for both of the iOS version? if not then you should use the rotation and interface orientation methods for both versions.

Comment: could you please give me an example of what you are talking about?

Comment: I didn't down vote but my guess is that you didn't even search on stackoverflow for the answer. There are many questions just like this one. Search first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**iOS5**

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

     return  YES;
}
```

**iOS6**

```
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate{

    return YES;
}
```

**Note**: If you are supporting both versions then you should add [both of the methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), they will be called according to the version you are running on your device/simulator.

It is good idea to add the method for supported orientations

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {    
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape ;
}
```

Comment: @MauriceA. You are welcome, it is very common question, there are number of questions and answer on this problem. You should read the documentation of UIViewController for more details.